# How to get the last data entry with greenDao?

Tags: android, greendao

I am using greenDao to manage my database and I need to get the last entry that was made. How do I do this? Is there a way to query the last ID entered or to somehow save it for later use?

Comment: The last entry could be anything. Please be more specific. What is your DB-Schema? Did you mean last entry to a table or of the whole db? Ask a specific question and you will get a specific answer. Otherwise you won't get any answer.

Comment: Sorry, by last entry I mean the last piece of data you placed into the DB. More accurately, if this were Dec. 10th, the last entry would refer to the closest data set in the DB to Dec. 10th.

Comment: Your database schema has to support a insert-timestamp column on each table in which you are interested in. Then you have to build some queries to get you the tablerow with the highest insertion date (or closest date, that's not neccessarily the same). Depending on how many tables are interesting for you you'll probably have to have some logic to select the Entity you want from the most actual ones. Provide your actual code/db-schema to get further more detailed help.

Comment: Do you know of any way of doing this without querying a block of entries from the DB and then applying logic to them to find the most recent? I was hoping there was some query method that would find the most recent.

Comment: Depends on your schema. Since you didn't ask a specific question I can't give a specific solution. Do you really want to get the last data entered into the db no matter what datatable?

Comment: use a "select" with "limit 1 " to only get the last record i suppose

Comment: If anyone has the same question, I guess the snippet you are looking for could be something like this: 
List list = myDao.queryBuilder().limit(1).list();

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
daoSession.getMyDao().queryBuilder().limit(1).orderDesc(MyDao.Properties.Id).list()
```